# How to separate 2 faces connects by an edge

Tags: modeling, edges

[image: in blender]

[image: drew this up]

I want to separate these so I can put one edge over the other later on.

Comment: Did you tried the "Rip" operator / tool?

Comment: Yup that works! I'll set that as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Edit Mode' and select the edges that u want to separate. Now select `Alt` + `M`. Then select **Faces by Edges** option. That will do the trick.

Comment: What version, as in some versions this command is used for merging